# Crystal Report formula field index changing on each new build

Tags: vb.net, indexing, crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-2008

I've got a Crystal Report which I made in `CR2008`, which I'm printing from my `vb.net` application. In this report, I have an image and a formula field.

The image formula (Under **Format Graphic > Picture > Graphic Location** is set to be the formula field called `@imgLocation`.

In my `vb.net` code, I have the following block to select the saved file path from the database, then fill `@imgLocation` with this value, to set the image that is being shown.

```
Try
   Dim logoPath As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("reportLogoPath") & ""

   If logoPath = "" Then
      MessageBox.Show("No logo path has been defined in the System Settings. Please set " & _
                       "one and try again.", "Load Report Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
      Exit Sub
   Else
     cReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item(2).Text = Chr(34) & logoPath & Chr(34)
   End If

Catch ex As Exception
   errorLog(ex)
End Try
```

I've seen this working twice. The image I want replaced the placeholder image when I had `FormulaFields.Item(2)`, but then I resized the image and it didn't work. I then changed the value of the index, and it worked with `FormulaFields.Item(4)`, but again stopped working when I resized the image.

Why is the index changing, and what is the way around it?

I tried using the named parameter option, but `FormulaFields.Item("@imgLocation")` gave me an error of

> Invalid Index

**EDIT**

As per @Bugs request, this is the report showing the correct string and image

[image]

Then, after deleting and re-saving the image (But in a slightly bigger size), the parameter was passed correctly still, but the placeholder image was shown instead.

[image]

This makes me think now that it's to do with image size, however, re-sizing it back to the original size still didn't show it again.

**EDIT 2**

Could it be do to with the fact that I'm loading a new form which contains the report viewer, rather than opening it from the same form?

```
 cReport.RecordSelectionFormula = selectionFormula
 Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
 Dim f As New frmReportViewer(con, cReport, 0)
 f.Show()

Private Sub frmReportViewer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  Try
     setFormSizes(Me, con)
     Me.Location = New Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2), 10)
     Me.Text = "Report Viewer"

     Dim logOnInfo As New TableLogOnInfo()
     Dim i As Integer

     For i = 0 To cReport.Database.Tables.Count - 1
          logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "comm_db"
          logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "Acplus2016!"
          cReport.Database.Tables.Item(i).ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo)
     Next i

     cReport.VerifyDatabase()

      crViewer.ReportSource = cReport
      crViewer.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None
      crViewer.Zoom(87)

  Catch ex As Exception
      errorLog(ex)

  End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bugs `cReport.SetParameterValue("@imgLocation", logoPath)` give the same invalid index error

Comment: @Bugs in Crystal Reports? I used the database expert to select the tables I wanted, then dragged the fields onto the report. The only `SQL` is in the code to get the image location from the database table, and assign it to the `logoPath` variable

Comment: Just deleting my comments as they no longer are required (don't want to create clutter). I've been trying to find a way round setting the image and I just can't seem to find a way. Just want to clarify before I go down another avenue. Are you setting just the one image in the page header? With it being a logo I'm assuming so but just want to confirm.

Comment: @Bugs Yes, there's only going to be one image on the report, but different users will have different images, which is why I'm getting it from the database

Comment: @Bugs Would you say it's a parameter problem or an image problem?

Comment: Definitely image. There is loads out there that I'm coming across that have a similar issue but often it's hacks to get the image to load. Simply passing it as a parameter I managed to do no problem. The image wasn't displayed but the parameter clearly had my passed value. Really annoying

Comment: It would seem it's an issue with using Crystal Report Viewer within VB. Did you manage at all to get the image to load correctly?

Comment: @Bugs Yeah, see the edit of the question, the screenshots are from when I ran it in the application itself. Sometimes works, then make changes to the image and it stops

Comment: Ah yes. That's strange. I read somewhere it was to do with the application not being able to have permission to run the file (image) but in my situation that definitely isn't the case. Does the image load correctly through Crystal Reports and then doesn't through the VB Crystal Report Viewer? I would just check the image within the report is definitely using the parameter to load the image.

Comment: @Bugs When I changed the formula in `@imgLocation` to just be the database field with it in, it didn't show the image, no.

Comment: I've provided an answer to help with adding parameters. I'm not sure if it will help you however. This doesn't solve the issue with the image not showing. That bit seems to be a problem I can't resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note my answer is addressing the part regarding *adding parameters*. For the moment the *no image available* placeholder is proving difficult to resolve on my side.

To add a parameter please follow these steps:

1. Add a parameter within Crystal Reports called **imageLocation**:

   [image]
2. After pressing **OK** you should have a parameter in your list like this:

   [image]
3. The following code will pass a value to the parameter:

   ```
   Dim cReport As New ReportDocument
   cReport.Load("C:\Report.rpt")

   If cReport.ParameterFields.Item("imageLocation") IsNot Nothing Then
       cReport.SetParameterValue("imageLocation", "\\SAGE200FS\Sage\StockImages\sc002.jpg")
   End If

   reportViewer.ReportSource = cReport
   ```
4. This is the output (I have added the parameter onto the report):

   [image]

> Note that if you are passing parameters and they are shown on the report, make sure you don't have `cReport.VerifyDatabase()` in place. This often throws up a dialog box asking for the parameter values.

Screenshot of dialog box:

[image]

By not calling `cReport.VerifyDatabase()` this will stop the dialog box from showing.

Now through Crystal Reports you can set the **Graphic Location** using a parameter. To do this, add the parameter to the report and suppress the field (as you don't want to see it). Then you can add the `Report Field` as the location.

1. Add parameter to report and suppress:

   [image]
2. Add `Report Field` as the **Graphic Location** for the `OLE Object`:~=

   [image]
3. Run the report and input the parameter. This will change the image accordingly. See both screenshots:

**SC001:**:

[image]

**INT4303:**

[image]

> This however does not seem to work through VB. The `ReportViewer` does not handle the change of images. Instead you are left with the default image. I'm unsure why this is the case and I'm *guessing* it's a bug with Crystal. If anyone knows of *why* this happens, feel free to comment.

**EDIT**

After discussing the smaller points in chat, we seem to have worked out that the issue arose because of the file path. Saving it to the database as `\\server\...\...\image.png` was not displaying, but after changing it to `Z:\...\...\image.png` it has worked fine every time. It was because of the file path, all along.

Comment: When I don't have the parameter on the report it says "invalid index" again, when I add it, a dialogue appears asking for me to enter its value?

Comment: Ah OK. I can't see your entire code but do you have `cReport.RefreshReport()` or anything like that? If you do this will throw up a dialog box asking for you to input it.

Comment: It's the `.VerifyDatabase` that's causing the dialog box I think. I have similar code and don't call `.VerifyDatabase`. We've never had an issue.

Comment: Ah, yes, it was. Yeah, this works as you expected. The parameter will show the correct location, but the image displayed isn't the correct one

Comment: @David yes that's as far as I could get. I'm unsure as to _why_ it doesn't change and I'm still looking but it doesn't look good. I'm hoping someone else will know why.

Comment: As a further test, I just ran this in Crystal Reports, rather than from the application. It prompted me asking to input the value for the parameter (As expected in this case). When I entered it, the parameter field showed the location, but the image didn't even change in Crystal.

Comment: @David, just check that you are using the parameter within `Graphic Location`. You may need to add the parameter to the report, supress it and use it as a report field. I'm not sure you can use the parameter directly you see.

Comment: Yep, done all of that, still the same. Definitely set it correctly in the Graphic Location too.

Comment: Hm strange. I've extended answer slightly to show what steps I took. It seems to be OK for me.

Comment: What image are you using as the placeholder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136890/discussion-between-bugs-and-david).